# VB.NET := Operator

Tags: vb.net, optional-variables

What does the following mean?

```
Class.Function(variable := 1 + 1)
```

What is this operator called, and what does it do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is used to assign optional variables, without assigning the previous ones.

```
sub test(optional a as string = "", optional b as string = "")
   msgbox(a & b)
end sub
```

you can now do

```
test(b:= "blaat")
'in stead of
test("", "blaat")
```

Comment: I also use it sometimes for required variables. For example if I have a function that takes multiple boolean flags (the horrors!) then I can do something like `DoTheThing(doItFast := True, doItNow := True...)` so that it's clear what flags I'm setting (as opposed to `DoTheThing(True, True, False, True, False, False, False)` :P)

Answer (score 0):

It assigns the optional parameter "variable" the value 2.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET supports this syntax for named (optional) parameters in method calls. This particular syntax informs `Class.Function` that its parameter `variable` is to be set to 2 (1 + 1).