# What does "Shift:=" mean in this VB6 code?

Tags: excel, vb6

I've run across the following line in a VB6 application.

```
mobjParentWrkBk.ExcelWorkBook.Application.Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Unfortunately Google and other search engines have not been very useful as they seem to omit the := part.

What would be a C# equivalent?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is Visual Basic syntax for optional named parameters. The `Insert` function has a parameter named `Shift`, which is being specified.

C#, as far as I know, doesn't have an equivalent for optional named parameters. Instead, you'd need to call the `Insert` method, specifying `Type.Missing` for all parameters other than `Shift`.

See also the following StackOverflow question: [VB.NET := Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204877/vbnet-operator)

UPDATE (2008-10-29):

C# 4.0 is set to introduce optional and named parameters. See this [blog entry on codebetter.com](http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2008/10/28/named-and-optional-arguments-in-c-4-0.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, the Shift part made me think it was some kind of language function, didn't think to look at the method parameters.

Comment: "specifying null for all parameters " - actually you should specify Type.Missing for missing optional parameters.

Comment: Because of SO, you answered my question less than 1 minute after I discovered :=, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Just to clarify John Rudy's response.

The sytax is optional (small 'o'), meaning you don't have to use it. In my experience, most VB6 coders don't use the syntax and instead prefer regular 'unnamed' parameters.

If you do choose to use it, all subsequent paramters in the sub procedure call must be named.

The named paramter syntax can be used on all parameters, whether or not the corresponding argument was declared using the VBA keyword `Optional` (capital 'O'). Consider, for example, this (slightly daft) VBA function with two parameters, one required and one `Optional`:

```
Private Function TimesTen( _
    ByVal Value As Long, _
    Optional ByVal Factor As Long = 10 _
) As Long
  TimesTen = Value * Factor
End Function
```

In VBA, I can call it using named parameters for the required parameter (the `Optional` paramter can simply be omitted in VBA, unlike in C#.NET for which `Type.Missing` must be used for all omitted `Optional` parameters):

```
  MsgBox TimesTen(Value:=9)
```

If I wanted to call it with the parameters in the 'wrong' order (why??) I can achieve this using named parameters:

```
  MsgBox TimesTen(Factor:=11, Value:=9)
```

Trying to use a regular 'unnamed' parameter call after a named one causes a compile error:

```
  MsgBox TimesTen(Value:=9, 11)
```

So why do VBA coders use named parameters if VB6 coders rarely do, even though they use essentially the same language? I think it is because the VBA generated by the MS Office applications' macro recorder tends to (always?) generate named parameters and many VBA coders learn programming this way.

Comment: It's a shame this isn't getting upvoted more ... I gave you +1 for the extra info.

Comment: yes this is a very interesting answer. I only just discovered := in some vb6 code and wondered what the delphi syntax was doing there. Now I know!

Answer (score 2):

VB6 and VB.net has optional parameters in method.
c# has the option to do method overloading.

VB6/VB.net way of saying Shift:=xlToRight allows passing value of a specific parameter by name.

e.g. 
public sub mymethod(optional a as integer = -1, optional b as integer=1)
...
end sub

I can call this method with mymethod(b:=10)

For c#, there could be 2 methods for this

```
void Shift()
{
defaultDirection = directionEnum.Left;
Shift(defaultDirection);
}

void Shift(directionEnum direction)
{
}
```

1 more thing.
Although you can call method just by passing parameters, adding parameter name when calling makes code a little more readable.
e.g. DoSomethingWithData(CustomerData:= customer, SortDirection:=Ascending)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's really all about Excel and how it handles inserts.  If you select a range of cells and right-click Insert you will be asked which direction to shift the cells.  This is from the Excel Help:

=======

Insert Method on Range Object

Inserts a cell or a range of cells into the worksheet or macro sheet and shifts other cells away to make space.

expression.Insert(Shift, CopyOrigin)

expression    Required. An expression that returns a Range object.

Shift   Optional Variant. Specifies which way to shift the cells. Can be one of the following XlInsertShiftDirection constants: xlShiftToRight or xlShiftDown. If this argument is omitted, Microsoft Excel decides based on the shape of the range.

CopyOrigin   Optional Variant. The copy origin.

===========

If you don't have the constants defined you can subsitute the following numbers

xlShiftDown: -4121
xlShiftToLeft: -4159
xlShiftToRight: -4161
xlShiftUp: -4162